# Maven installation and a higher version of Java in dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have java project A implemented using Java 17. Project A has a dependency on project B which has been implemented with Java 21. I cannot upgrade A to Java 21 due to other dependencies.

How can I install project A using Maven (3.8.8) with B dependency?

I have installed project B with Maven 3.8.8 and Java 21. When I run `mvn clean install` on project A with Maven 3.8.8 and Java 17 it produces this error (this is just a part of the error, basically it is unable to access any of the classes from project B):

```
[INFO] 61 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.352 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-12-21T07:52:00+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project Main: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/alzbe/Documents/mff_mgr/Diplomka/Apps/projectA/src/main/java/cz/cuni/matfyz/projectA/schemaconversion/SchemaConverter.java:[9,29] cannot access cz.matfyz.projectB.schema.Key
[ERROR]   bad class file: C:\Users\alzbe\.m2\repository\cz\matfyz\projectB\1.0-SNAPSHOT\core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar(/cz/matfyz/projectB/schema/Key.class)
[ERROR]     class file has wrong version 65.0, should be 61.0
[ERROR]     Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
[ERROR] /C:/Users/alzbe/Documents/mff_mgr/Diplomka/Apps/projectA/src/main/java/cz/cuni/matfyz/projectA/schemaconversion/SchemaConverter.java:[10,31] cannot access cz.matfyz.projectB.category.Signature
[ERROR]   bad class file: C:\Users\alzbe\.m2\repository\cz\matfyz\projectB\1.0-SNAPSHOT\core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar(/cz/matfyz/projectB/category/Signature.class)
[ERROR]     class file has wrong version 65.0, should be 61.0
[ERROR]     Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
[ERROR] /C:/Users/alzbe/Documents/mff_mgr/Diplomka/Apps/projectA/src/main/java/cz/cuni/matfyz/projectA/schemaconversion/SchemaConverter.java:[11,31] cannot access cz.matfyz.projectB.category.Morphism
[ERROR]   bad class file: C:\Users\alzbe\.m2\repository\cz\matfyz\projectB\1.0-SNAPSHOT\core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar(/cz/matfyz/projectB/category/Morphism.class)
[ERROR]     class file has wrong version 65.0, should be 61.0
```

How can I let Maven know, that project A uses Java 17, but dependency B uses Java 21.

The way I set the java version for Maven is through `$JAVA_HOME`.

This is the .pom file of project A:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProjectA</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <exec.mainClass>ProjectA.main</exec.mainClass>
        
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
            </exclusions>               
            <version>2.4.13</version>
        </dependency> 
        <!--https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver--> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb.spark/mongo-spark-connector--> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-spark-connector_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>            
            <groupId>cz.matfyz</groupId>
            <artifactId>ProjectB</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version> 
         <!--   <scope>compile</scope> -->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies> 
    
    <build>
        <plugins>           
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration> 
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>                          
                                <mainClass>ProjectA.main</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                </configuration>                
            </plugin>
        
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.13</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin> 
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

From searching the internet I have found that a similar problem could be solved with Toolchains. However, that would only solve the problem if I wanted to compile different parts of project A with different java versions. My situation is different - I want Maven to be able to install project A with a dependency on project B with a higher version of Java.

Thank you for any advice

Comment: First it would be helpful what: `it crashes on the Java version of project B.` exactly means? The full output of the failure can help here... also if you have a dependency which requires JDK21 than your project has to use JDK21 as well... there is simply no  way around that... apart form what I can see you are using very outdate version of spring boot (2.4.X https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot/#support) and also the plugins you are using are not up-to-date... as well as your dependencies like junit 3.8? and JUnit Jupiter ? What are you really using?

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I have added the error it produces. Project A has already undergone java upgrade in the recent past (from 8 to 17) to match the version in B, which used to be 17. But now B got upgraded to 21 and my trouble began. I am needing to keep A at 17, because (as far as I now) the only version of Spark which supports java 21 is the latest realese (3.5.0), however this is not compatible with my Spring release and upgrading spring lead to another set of incompatibility problems. Do you have any further advice. And thank you again:)

Comment: As already mentioned bx the answer and by me.. If JDK21 is required there is no other way to upgrade the whole project step by step.. Upgrade all dependencies to most recent versions step by step after that upgrade SB to next minor version SB 2.5.X after that SB 2.6X etc. up to the most recent version SB 3.2.1 (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Older-Release-Notes) and also 2.7.X to 3.0 and so on https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki

Comment: That should have been done that long time ago .. SB 2.4 support ended in 2021 which means it should have been started to upgrade to 2.5.x in 2020 (Testing with Milestones etc.) also you should upgrade your tools Maven to most recent version 3.9.6 etc. furthermore the error shows exactly what I expected. The dependecy has been compiled with JDK21 so to consume that you have to migrate to JDK 21.. there is no other choice.. One more thing. If you don't upgrade you will always being faced with security issue which will not be fixed anymore because you are on old outdated versions..

Answer (score 3):

Not possible.

If your dependency needs Java 21, then you need Java 21.